# Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals - Matlab error

Tags: matlab, numerical-analysis

I am trying to do the euler method to solve the Initial Value problem using the matlab

```
    close all; 
clear; 
clc;

a=0; %initial limit
b=1.2;% final limit
n=20; %Number of points
h=(b-a)/n; %step length

t=a:h:b;
wn(i+1)=[0.5 zeros(1,n)];

for i=1:n
wn(i+1)=wn(i)+h*(wn(i)-t(i)^2)+1;
end

yActual=(t+1).^2-0.5*exp(t);

err=abs(wn-yActual);

 disp('==============================================================================')
disp('   t_i              w_i                  y_i              |w_i-y_i| ')
disp('               (Approximation)      (Actual Value)         (Error) ')
disp('==============================================================================')


for i=1:n+1
fprintf('%0.5f \t %0.5f \t %0.5f \t %0.5f \n',t(i),wn(i),yActualI(i),err(i));
end

plot(t,wn,'-or','Linewidth',2)
hold on
gird on
plot(t,yActual,'-b','Linewidth',2)


xlabel('t')
ylabel('y')
legend('Euler Approximation','Actual Value')
```

but when I run the code it shows me this error and I searched a lot and not finding a way to solve it:

```
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Error in Assignment3_Q2 (line 11)
wn(i+1)=[0.5 zeros(1,n)];
```

How I can solve it? please if you can show me by code because I am beginner in MatLab

Comment: In the MATLAB editor, turn on the debugger to stop on error. Then run your program. It will stop at like 11 where your error happens. Now examine the value of `i` at this point. Does it have the value you expect? Examine your code around this point, why does `i` not have the value you expect? Where do you set its value?

Comment: At the line where the error is, `i` is defined as the complex unit as that's the default and you haven't reassigned it yet (although you do later, which is bad practice). You asked Matlab for the `i+1`th element of a vector and it understandably threw an error.

Answer (score 0):

There are some typo/errors in the code...The following runs. The exact reason of the error on line 11 in your original code is that, without variable declaration (e.g., i = n), i is the unit imaginary part in a complex number (i.e., 0 + 1i), but that's probably an unnecessary detail to your purpose.

```
close all; 
clear; 
clc;

a=0; %initial limit
b=1.2;% final limit
n=20; %Number of points
h=(b-a)/n; %step length

t=a:h:b;
wn=[0.5 zeros(1,n)];

for i=1:n
wn(i+1)=wn(i)+h*(wn(i)-t(i)^2)+1;
end

yActual=(t+1).^2-0.5*exp(t);

err=abs(wn-yActual);

 disp('==============================================================================')
disp('   t_i              w_i                  y_i              |w_i-y_i| ')
disp('               (Approximation)      (Actual Value)         (Error) ')
disp('==============================================================================')


for i=1:n+1
fprintf('%0.5f \t %0.5f \t %0.5f \t %0.5f \n',t(i),wn(i),yActual(i),err(i));
end

plot(t,wn,'-or','Linewidth',2)
hold on
grid on
plot(t,yActual,'-b','Linewidth',2)


xlabel('t')
ylabel('y')
legend('Euler Approximation','Actual Value')
```